# Using the value of Row() in the formula bar itself - Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I just know basic functions in excel. I was tasked to making an excel doc with some data. I have inputted data in the form of a table. To explain my problem better, I will give an example along with a screenshot.

[image]

As seen in the image, I have different columns starting from sl.no., name, till output. 6 columns in total. I have 4 rows. I want to find the row with the maximum output, and then I want to copy the values from that same row but not from all the columns and paste it somewhere else.

So in the excel sheet in the image, the output 612 is the highest. I want the sl.no., name, days and output copied to another location.

I am able to find the highest value, 612 in this case. I can also get the row number which is 8 in this example, using match() and max() formulas. I wanted to know if its possible for me to, once I get the value of the row, that is 8 here, through match and max or even row(), can I use it in the formula bar.

So here, in the image, I want B14 to have the value of B8. If I knew beforehand, then I could just directly type in B14, "= B8". But since I don't know the value, can I write something in the B14 tile like, `=B(MATCH(MAX(G5:G8),G5:MG8,0))` or `=$B$MATCH(MAX(G8:G8),G5:G8,0)`. I know these don't work. But is it possible for something like this?
Or if not, What could be a solution, if any? I don't know all the functions of Excel.

I was unable to find a similar question online.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps could use one of the followings:

[image]

---

```
=CHOOSECOLS(FILTER($B$5:$G$8,MAX($G$5:$G$8)=$G$5:$G$8),1,2,4,6)
```

---

Or, [image]

```
=INDEX($B$5:$G$8,MATCH(MAX($G$5:$G$8),$G$5:$G$8,0),MATCH(B13:E13,B4:G4,0))
```

---

Or,

### [image]

```
=INDEX($B$5:$G$8,AGGREGATE(15,7,(ROW($G$5:$G$8)-ROW($G$5)+1)/
  (AGGREGATE(14,7,$G$5:$G$8,1)=$G$5:$G$8),1),MATCH(B13:E13,B4:G4,0))
```

---

Or,

[image]

---

```
=CHOOSECOLS(TAKE(SORT(B5:G8,6,-1),1),XMATCH(B13:E13,B4:G4))
```

---

Or, [image]

---

```
=FILTER(XLOOKUP(MAX(G5:G8),G5:G8,B5:G8),{1,1,0,1,0,1})
```

---